# GPU pre-computed inverse optimization

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, gpu

I have the following code (ray-box intersection):

```
float interBox(vec3 bmin, vec3 bmax, vec3 ro, vec3 rd){
vec3 t1 = (bmin-ro)/rd;
vec3 t2 = (bmax-ro)/rd;

float tmin = min(t1.x, t2.x);
float tmax = max(t1.x, t2.x);

tmin = max(tmin, min(t1.y, t2.y));
tmax = min(tmax, max(t1.y, t2.y));

tmin = max(tmin, min(t1.z, t2.z));
tmax = min(tmax, max(t1.z, t2.z));

return (tmax-tmin)<0? -1: tmin;
```

I call this function with the same rd parameter more than 40-50 times in a shader. I thought that pre-computing 1.0/rd would save some time. However, the shader performance was worse than the naive implementation. How can this be possible?

Comment: How much worse? 5% worse or 100% worse?

Comment: How is `rd` computed?

Comment: Who's to say the GLSL compiler doesn't already do that optimization? It's pretty trivial. If this were D3D, you could look at the HLSL bytecode of the compiler's better version vs. your own optimization attempt no matter what GPU you're using. If you're on an NV GPU, the GLSL program binary often includes a text assembly you can take a look at... I have to wonder if it's really worth the effort though?

Comment: @Mikhail  ~10-15% worse.

Comment: @Andon I'm using a Nvidia GPU on Linux. How can I get this assembly? (I can use Windows if that is the only way).

Comment: @dv1729: The extension specification for [`GL_ARB_get_program_binary`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/get_program_binary.txt)  has some example code written in C that shows how to do this. The resulting output is implementation-specific, but NV drivers tend to include human readable assembly that you can browse through.